# rails activerecord special relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

My project is to make simple web link directory.

I have two models:

```
class Categorie < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :sites, class_name: "Site"
end

class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :categories
end
```

Now I need to extract all url for recursive category for example:

```
cat : 
animals : 
   cat
   dog
   ..
```

And I need all sites where

```
cat = animals%
```

Comment: Looks like an simple interview question, could you please show your efforts?

Comment: im new in ruby rails and i cant find solution :(

Comment: your question is not clear ...

Comment: category : 
catid= 1 name="metal"
catid= 2 name="animal"
catid= 3 name="animal/cat"
catid= 4 name="animal/dog"

site : 
cat_id =1 url = http://www.blablabla.com
cat_id =2 url = http://caty.blog.com
cat_id =2 url = http://pampam.blog.com
cat_id =2 url = http://caty2.blog.com
cat_id =3 url = http://cat1.blog.com
cat_id =3 url = http://cat2.blog.com
i need all urtl related to animal*

Comment: while defining one-to-one association you use should use singular table name: `has_one :category`